# Jquery mobile dialog - multiple &ui-state=dialog in URL

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile-dialog

For some reason &ui-state=dialog gets appended to the URL everytime I open the jquery mobile dialog using changepage.

Ex:    `/search-results.html?m_search=iphone#&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog`

```
 $('.legClick').bind('click', function (e) {
            jQuery.mobile.changePage('#test');
        })
```

Close button code:

```
<a data-inline="true" data-theme="d" data-role="button"
        data-rel="back" href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-b" aria-disabled="false"
        data-cqpath="10267989408824866797448481664492725584"
        style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;width:100%">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span  class="ui-btn-text">Close</span></span>
</a>
```

Do I need to include any other option to make sure this particular parameter doesn't get appended multiple times in the URL?